# Google youtube API fails to login with bad request and invalid Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-data-api

Google youtube API fails to login with bad request and invalid Key
I renewed my credentials at google console several times.

## change API key Several time but problem is same.

The code I´m using:

```js
var channelname = 'mipaltan';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
        part: 'contentDetails',
        forUsername: 'mipaltan',
        key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
    },
 function (data) {
     $.each(data.item, function (i, item) {
         console.log(item);
         pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
         getVids(pid);
     })
 }
);
    function getVids(pid) {
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: 10,
            playListId: pid,
            key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
        },

         function (data) {
             var output;
             $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                 console.log(item);
                 vidsTitle = item.snippet.title;

                 output = '<li>"+ vidsTitle +"</li>'; 
                 // Append to results 
                 $('#results').append(output);
              })
         }
 );
    }
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title> Get Video Title</title>
<style>
body {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
}
#container 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
    margin: auto;
 padding:15px;
}
</style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
       <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="container">
           <h1> YouTube Video Title</h1>
           <ul id="results"></ul>
       </div>
      </form>
   </body>
    

</html>
```

## Same API Key I'm using other page it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its items not item and playlistId not playListId

```js
var channelname = 'mipaltan';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
      part: 'contentDetails',
      forUsername: 'mipaltan',
      key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
    },
    function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
        getVids(pid);
      })
    }
  );

  function getVids(pid) {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 10,
        playlistId: pid,
        key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
      },

      function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) { 
          vidsTitle = item.snippet.title;
          output = '<li>'+ vidsTitle +'</li>';
          // Append to results 
          $('#results').append(output);
        })
      }
    );
  }
});
```

```css
body {
      background: #f4f4f4;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666;
    }
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
      <h1> YouTube Video Title</h1>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much My Dear Friends, Im not forget you,

Comment: don't forget to click the green check near my answer to accept it